# Alt-Tab Key combination closes my fullscreen tkinter app

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen

I have a fullscreen Tkinter app that closes when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed. Does this happen with all fullscreen Tkinter apps? I have used `overrideredirect(1)` to make the app fullscreen, I have also bound a shortcut to change it from fullscreen to normal and vice-versa. I tried to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to change the app to normal mode and then press alt and tab using the keyboard module (press and release the shortcut). It doesn't work. Is there any way to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or leave the app open after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed, it changes apps and closes my app)?

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)

def fullscreen(*args):
    root.overrideredirect(1)

def normalscreen(*args):
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.bind('<Control-q>', fullscreen)

root.bind('<Control-q>', normalscreen)
root.mainloop()
```

I am mainly targeting Windows.

Comment: Your `bind()` calls have syntax errors.

Comment: Oh...sorry, didn't notice that...is it fine now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234055/discussion-between-the-amateur-coder-and-klaus-d).

Comment: There are especially for this built- in ways to achieve this. Do a quick research on `.wm_attributes('-fullscreen')` should work on all platforms. Overrideredirect does something different as you think.

Comment: @Thingamabobs, realized only now that you might've misunderstood why I used `overrideredirect()`. I wanted to use a custom title bar. I was actually asking if there's a way to prevent the app from being closed (and just minimized/back to normal as it was before), as either the app got closed, or it might've just lost focus as it switches apps, so the app itself might have not been closed and was just not visible which made me think that the app got closed.